# ARCore: accessing camera image data from frame.acquireCameraImage

Tags: rendering, augmented-reality, arcore

I have an app in Java which needs to get the camera image from ARCore for custom rendering. Recently, two new APIs have been added to ARCore (v1.1.0) which should support this. Well, everything else works for me except these two calls. Both calls are failing with same error (SIGINIT):
[SIGINIT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0scnv.png)

and I have this message in the Logcat:

**04-18 14:52:32.007 32623-32623/ A/Ion: [java/com/google/vr/dynamite/client/native/dynamite_client.cc:74] CHECK failed: expression='"env"'**

**04-18 14:52:32.007 32623-32623/ A/Ion: Dumping stack:**

relevant code is:

```
    try
    {
        // Obtain the current frame from session.
        mSession.setCameraTextureName( mTextureId );
        Frame frame = mSession.update();
        TrackingState trackingState = frame.getCamera().getTrackingState();
        if ( trackingState == TrackingState.TRACKING )
        {
            // Compute lighting, this is also crashing
            //final float[] colorCorrectionRgba = new float[4];
            //frame.getLightEstimate().getColorCorrection( colorCorrectionRgba, 0 );

            //getPixelIntensity works fine
            float lightIntensity = frame.getLightEstimate().getPixelIntensity();
            Log.d( TAG, " light intensity is " + lightIntensity );

            //This is also crashing
            android.media.Image image = frame.acquireCameraImage();
            //do something useful with the image
            image.close();
```

app level build.gradle has the following entry under dependencies:

**implementation 'com.google.ar:core:1.1.0'**

and I have tried this with both proguard enabled and disabled.

Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong?

PS: In case it's not clear, the failing calls are `frame.acquireCameraImage()` and `frame.getLightEstimate().getColorCorrection()`.

Comment: Did you found something?